# Error while making dataset Connection with Snowflake in Azure ADF dataset

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, azure-adf, linked-service

I have two linked services one for SQL and other for Snowflake.While  making snowflake dataset connection in ADF it throws below error:
Error details
Error code
9602
Details
ERROR [22000] Cannot perform SELECT. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.
Activity ID: 5d0a5741-1efc-42b0-a835-045bb9bba1f8

It worked for the first time but later it is giving error.
I checked the privileges to my role and that is sufficient. The name of the Database is also correct all in capital letters.

Comment: If you call "show databases" in a Snowflake Worksheet, does the name of the database also appear in all capitals?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default database on the user using the [ALTER USER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html#alter-user) command in Snowflake:

```sql
ALTER USER user1 SET DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = database_name
```